# Fetch snippet from Google Search with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-search, google-search-api

The following code allowed me to extract an URL from Google Search :

```
  const apiKey = "";
  const searchEngineId = "";

  const urlQuery =
    `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={{apiKey}}&cx={{searchEngineId}}&q={{query}}&num=10`;

  const url = urlQuery
    .replace("{{apiKey}}", encodeURIComponent(apiKey))
    .replace("{{searchEngineId}}", encodeURIComponent(searchEngineId))
    .replace("{{query}}", encodeURIComponent(query));

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  try {
    const res = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    let results = res.items.map(e => {
      return e.formattedUrl;
    });

    let output;

    if (company) {
      output = results.filter(e => {
        return e.includes("/company/");
      });
    } else {
      output = results.filter(function(e, i) {
        return e.includes("/in/");
      });
    }

    output = getResults(output,index);

    return output;
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw new Error (err)
  }
}

const getResults = (data,index) => {
  let res;

  if (index == 0) {
    res = data.map((e,i) => `${i+1} ${e}`);
    res.flat();
  } else {
    res = data[index-1];
  }
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
```

I now want to extract the content of the search result, and I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

I have the query that I want to get the result for, but I'm a bit lost on how can I get the text now.

Thanks for your kind help!